# Video seeking in Google Chrome: How to handle continuous Partial Content requests?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, html5-video

This question may be a little overwhelming, but I feel close to understanding the way video seeking works in Google Chrome, but it's still very confusing to me and support is difficult to find.

If I am not mistaken, Chrome initially sends a request header with Range **bytes=0-** to test if the server understands **Partial Content** requests, and expects the server to respond with status code **206**.

I have read the following answers to get a better understanding:
*Need more rep to link them, their topics are:*
**can't seek html5 video or audio in chrome**
**HTML5 video will not loop**
**HTTP Range header**

My server is powered by Node.js and I am having trouble with getting continuous range requests out of chrome during playback. When a video is requested, the server receives a bytes=0-, the server then responds with status code 206 and
then the media player *breaks*.

My confusion is with with the response header, because I am not sure how to
construct my response header and handle eventual range requests:

1. Do I respond with a status code *200* or *206* initially?
   When I respond with *206* I only receive bytes=0-, but when I respond with
   *200* I receive bytes=0- and after that bytes=355856504-.
   If I were to subtract 355856504 of the total Content-Length of the video file, the result is 58, and bytes=0-58 seems like a valid Content-Range?
   But after those two requests, I receive no more range requests from Chrome.

I am also unsure if the Content-Range in the response header should looks like "bytes=0-58" or like "bytes=0-58/355856562" for example.

Here is the code

```
if(req.headers.range) console.info(req.headers.range); // prints bytes=0-

const type = rc.sync(media, 0, 32); // determines mime type
const size = fs.statSync(media)["size"]; // determines content length

// String range, initially "bytes=0-" according to Chrome
var Strange = req.headers.range;

res.set({
  "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
  "Content-Type": ft(type).mime,
  "Content-Length": size-Strange.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")[0],
  "Content-Range": Strange+size+"/"+size
});

//res.status(206); // one request from chrome, then breaks
res.status(200);   // two requests from chrome, then breaks

// this prints 35585604-58, whereas i expect something like 0-58
console.log("should serve range: "+
  parseInt(Strange.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")[0]) +"-"+
  parseInt(size-Strange.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")[0])
);

// this function reads some bytes from 'media', and then streams it:
fs.createReadStream(media, {
  start: 0,
  end: parseInt(size-Strange.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")[0]) // 58
}).pipe(res);
```

Screenshots of the request and response headers when status code is 200:
[first response and request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnCzc.png)
[second response and request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txqBm.png)

Screenshot of the request and response header when status code is 206:
*Need more rep, to show another screenshot*
Essentially the request is:
"Range: bytes=0-"
and the Content-Range response is:
"bytes=0-355856562/355856562"

Comment: Why not just use [send](https://github.com/pillarjs/send)?

Comment: The send library works like a charm, but I still don't know how the implementation and handling of Partial Content requests work exactly.

Comment: Chrome may be asking for `bytes=355856504-` to get the end of the file, as that is where some video encodings keep necessary metadata for playback. See https://superuser.com/questions/856025/any-downsides-to-always-using-the-movflags-faststart-parameter

Answer (score 1):

One apparent error is that you are returning an invalid value in the `Range` header. See the [sepcification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) - it should be `0-355856561/355856562` since the second value after the dash is the last byte position not length.

Comment: But is 0-35585651 even valid? It seems like a absurd large range to respond with. I am not sure why Chrome requests "bytes=355856504".

Comment: Well that is only 33 MB, why should it not be valid? Chrome only asks within a range you have specified somewhere earlier in a `Content-Length` header.